# Can OpenZeppelin Defender call nonReentrant functions?

Tags: openzeppelin, gas-limit, reentrant-attacks, defender

I am getting this error running a transaction with a relayer in Open Zeppelin Defender:

```
cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit
```

I know that you get this error when the transaction is going to fail. This is the function I am trying to execute:

```
    function mint(address _to) external onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE) nonReentrant returns(uint256) {
        require(random == false, "Variant only available as random mint");
        require(getRemainingSupplyOfTokenType(1) > 0);
        uint256 mintedToken = doMint(_to, totalSupply(), 1);
        return mintedToken;
    }
```

I have already checked that all possible accounts have the `MINTER_ROLE` assigned to them and that all `require` statements are not being triggered.

Is it possible that `nonReentrant` functions are not compatible with Open Zeppelin Defender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Open Zeppelin Defender works with `nonReentrant` functions.

The problem I was having was related to something else.